# Div element moves to the left when I hide first div

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I have 3 boxes and they are showing and hiding when you press the button. The problem is when I hide the first box, the middle box moves to the left... Here is the website when all of three boxes are showed-[All boxes showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWGe2.jpg). Here is what happens when I close the first one-[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w07FU.jpg). And I have one more problem... The 3rd box is away from the other boxes and too close to the right side-[The 3rd box problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn3zO.jpg). Please help me and thank you! :D

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-size: auto 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right !important;
}
  
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0074D9;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: white !important;
 font-family:arial;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #0047b3 !important;
}

.active {
    background-color:#0047b3;
}

a:link{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:hover{
 color:#001f3f;
}
a:active{
 color:#001f3f;
}

hr{
 height:3px;
 background-color:#0080ff;
 border:0px;
 transform: translateY(-95%);
 margin: 35px -9999rem;
    padding: 0.10rem 9999rem;
}
button{
 background-color:#0074D9;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-family:arial;
 border-color:transparent;
 padding:9px;
 font-size:18;
 width:150px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 27px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
button:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
button:hover{
 background-color:#0047b3;
}
button:active{
 color:#0047b3;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#left {
 float:left;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    margin: 56px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#middle {
 bottom:50%;
 display:block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
 position:fixed !important;
 top:30% !important;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 30px;
 margin-left:-20px !important;
 margin-right:-20px !important;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
 
#right {
 float:right;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding:30px;
    margin: 56px 25px -20px !important;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
 height: 130px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Moj web</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
<body background="http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<script>
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiv");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function showDiver() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiver");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
function showDiverer() {
    var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiverer");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<center><div>
<button onclick="showDiv()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
<button onclick="showDiverer()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
<button onclick="showDiver()" style= "margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
</div></center>
<br>
<br>
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">
<div  id="left">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="welcomeDiver" style="display:none;">
<div id="right">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="welcomeDiverer" style="display:none;">
<div  id="middle">
<p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br>
Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br>
Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you dont want them to be moved to the left? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you fixed the Left property of middle div like

```
left: 50%;
```

or

left: 250px;

copy the code below to check the change. if it is posibble why don't you use bootstrap css

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-size: auto 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right !important;
}
  
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0074D9;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 color: white !important;
 font-family:arial;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #0047b3 !important;
}

.active {
    background-color:#0047b3;
}

a:link{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
a:hover{
 color:#001f3f;
}
a:active{
 color:#001f3f;
}

hr{
 height:3px;
 background-color:#0080ff;
 border:0px;
 transform: translateY(-95%);
 margin: 35px -9999rem;
    padding: 0.10rem 9999rem;
}
button{
 background-color:#0074D9;
 border-radius:10px;
 font-family:arial;
 border-color:transparent;
 padding:9px;
 font-size:18;
 width:150px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 27px;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}
button:visited{
 color:#0074D9;
}
button:hover{
 background-color:#0047b3;
}
button:active{
 color:#0047b3;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#left {
 float:left;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    margin: 56px;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial !important;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:white;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


#middle {
 left: 40%;
 bottom:50%;
 display:block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
 position: fixed !important;;
 top:30% !important;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 30px;
 margin-left:-20px !important;
 margin-right:-20px !important;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
 
#right {
 float:right;
 display: block;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    padding:30px;
    margin: 56px 25px -20px !important;
 vertical-align:-200%;
 font-family:arial;
 border-radius:25px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-shadow: 2px 1px #0080ff;
 font-style: oblique;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-size:18;
 background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ), url('http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#left, #middle, #right{
 height: 130px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Moj web</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body background="http://img.wallpaper.sc/desktop/images/5k/desktop-pc-5120x2880-wallpaper_00019.jpg">

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script>
        function showDiv() {
            var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiv");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function showDiver() {
            var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiver");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function showDiverer() {
            var x = document.getElementById("welcomeDiverer");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>

    <center>
        <div>
            <button onclick="showDiv()" style="margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
            <button onclick="showDiverer()" style="margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
            <button onclick="showDiver()" style="margin-right: 75px">Pritisni me!</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>
 
  

  <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;">
   <div id="left">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiver" style="display:none;">
   <div id="right">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeDiverer" style="display:none;">
   <div id="middle">
    <p>Zdravo, ja sam Kenan!<br> Ovo je moja testna stranica na kojoj radim dosta kratko!<br> Na ovoj stranici mozete viditi HTML, CSS i JS jezike!<br>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 
    <br>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would simply, in this case, ensure that you only set "visibility" to hidden and keep the "display" how it was. This will ensure that no content is "moved", as the "hidden" element was never "removed", only hidden.

Also, if you were to set left and top positions explicitly, the browser would usually take this into account when rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this issue may be solved for the original author of the question, as he have already marked the best answer, but for those who would face a similar problem I would suggest some ideas which can be much more vital within the context of real project:

1. Positioning the elements with **fixed** value of pixels or percentage may ruin your page design when your visitor looks at it from a smaller device - laptop, tablet or phone
2. Mind that hiding with `display` or just `visibility` property **doesn't** work with transitions smoothly, so if you would ever need to animate such hiding effect - use `opacity` or any other suitable techniques
3. Look at the code - there is Jquery connected, doesn't it feel weird to use those 3 similar scripts taken from w3schools? Why not trying native jquery  `.toggle()`, here is [a quick link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
4. Never forget using semantic and **clear** markup. If you have separate stylesheet file, why putting styles inline? Just put them into the CSS file